# Using Variable in foreach() as array name PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have been making a clock which displays schedules based on which day it is so I have created 7 arrays with schedules in them. Now I need to write a foreach statement that takes the date:

```
 $day = date("D");
```

Then uses the foreach function on that array like:

```
 foreach ($day as &$value) {
 }
```

When I do this though it gives me an error because it wants me to use the direct array variable.

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/johfin16/johnfinberg.com/php/functions-new.php on line 24

Here is an example of one of my arrays.

```
 $Mon = array("08:10am-08:30am-Morning Meeting",
              "08:35am-09:55am-A Block", 
              "10:05am-11:25am-B Block",
              "11:30am-12:05pm-First Lunch",
              "12:05pm-12:40pm-Second Lunch", 
              "12:40pm-02:00pm-C Block", 
              "02:05pm-03:25pm-D Block");
```

Is there a way to work around this without creating a bunch of if statements?

Comment: `$day` isn't an array, it's a string.

Comment: you must use switch() not foreach() because $day is a string

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `foreach` when there's just one day?

Comment: In each day there are multiple classes which need to be pulled from the array.

Comment: which classes are you talking about? where's the rest of the code?

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use [*variable variables*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). So it should be:

```
$day = &${date('D');
foreach ($day as &$value) {
    ...
}
```

However, variable variables are generally poor programming practice. Whenever you find yourself needing them, it's a sign that you should be using an associative array instead of separate variables. So your code should be:

```
$calendar = array(
    'Mon' => array("08:10am-08:30am-Morning Meeting","08:35am-09:55am-A Block", "10:05am-11:25am-B Block", "11:30am-12:05pm-First Lunch", "12:05pm-12:40pm-Second Lunch", "12:40pm-02:00pm-C Block", "02:05pm-03:25pm-D Block"),
    'Tue' => array(...),
    ...
);
```

Then you can do:

```
$day = &$calendar[date('D')];
foreach ($day as &$value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Martin Thanks. Feel free to edit obvious typos like that.

Comment: I would, but as it was a brand new answer I often find that the writer edits the answer, and it's a waste of time if I fix the typo while you're editing and then you save and overwrite my previous fix.... I've had this a few times so was just mentioning incase you were already on an edit `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

The switch function can be used to set one array to $active and then that array can be used in the foreach function. Ex:

```
switch ($day) {
case "Mon":
    $active = $Mon;
    break;
case "Tue":
    $active = $Tue;
    break;
case "Wed":
    $active = $Wed;
    break;
default:
    $active = $Special;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In each day there are multiple classes which need to be pulled from the array.

**NO**

Because you have:

```
$day = date("D");
```

So whatever `$day` contained before this line is reached, classes, arrays, variables, etc. is forgotten and `$day` suddenly *just* becomes ONLY the result of `date("D")`.

You may be wanting to add `date("D")` as an array element (ie one of numerous items in an array), therefore you would do:

```
$day[] = date("D");
```

This will add the `date("D")` value to an array of multiple `$days`, this can then be cycled through with a `foreach` loop. For each day.